# Bumblebee does not work in my Lenovo g580 laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, bumblebee

I'm pulling my hair trying to get this out.

Since I know there is an issue with bumblebee and my laptop I've installed one of the latest stable kernels, so `uname -r` gives me `3.12.1-031201-generic`

Now `lspci -nn | grep '\[030[02]\]:'` shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
```

But still unable to run optirun, with throws (`optirun -vv firefox`):

```
[ 1029.729132] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1029.729505] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 1029.729560] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1029.729567] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 1029.729579] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

The nvidia drivers I'm trying to use are nvidia-319-updates, just in case olders won't recognize my GPU

I don't know wich other info could be important, here are is more info.

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d3000000-d33fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Bumblebee.conf:

```
Driver=nvidia

[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-319-updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

If I do a modprobe nvidia i get:

```
vivo@vivoPC:~$ modprobe nvidia
FATAL: Module nvidia not found.
vivo@vivoPC:~$ modprobe nvidia-319-updates
FATAL: Module nvidia_319_updates not found.
```

Please, tell if you need any more info

Comment: A few questions have been already asked with similar error messages. Try searching for `[bumblebee] daemon`, and see if this helps or add links to related but not helpful questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all those users with a lenovo or any new laptop with problems detecting your two devices:

All those instructions are on a fresh install. (yes, I reinstalled it...again)

**- Update your kernel to a 3.9 or highter**

Instructions (thanks to Mitch):

To install Linux Kernel 3.9.4, just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo update-grub2
```

For 64bit, just change:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-headers-3.9.4-030904_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.4-saucy/linux-image-3.9.4-030904-generic_3.9.4-030904.201305241545_amd64.deb
```

Note: You may have to restart your computer after the first command.

**- Install bumblebee rigurously as it says bumblebee's main page**

[Bumblebee Project](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Important the part where you have to edit the /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia (or /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau if using the noveau driver) and specify the correct BusID by following the instructions therein.

This means, uncomment the `#  BusID "PCI:01:00:0"` line (remove the '#') if your 3D card is in that bus (find it out with `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'`).

**- Install primus (thanks to webupd8 dot org)**

```
sudo apt-get install primus
```

64bit: you also need to install "primus-libs-ia32:i386" (note that if you're using the Primus PPA, the package you need to install is "primus-lib:i386"):

```
sudo apt-get install primus-libs-ia32:i386
```

Then, change the "Bridge" option in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf to "primus". You can also directly call Primus from optirun via command line, like this:

optirun -b primus APP

**- Test it**

```
optirun glxspheres
optirun -b primus glxspheres
```

Hope this may help any lost soul

Answer (score 0):

This is from [the docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee):

> In order to use Bumblebee it is necessary add yourself (and other users) to the `bumblebee` group:
>
> ```
> # gpasswd -a $USER bumblebee
> ```
>
> where `$USER` is the login name of the user to be added. Then log off and on again to apply the group changes.

Is your user in the `bumblebee` group? (You can use this command "as is", normally `$USER` will expand to the currently logged-in user. Have to execute it as `root` though -- just for setting up, not for using `optirun`.)